# How to remove correlated subquery in my subselect (due to presto limitation)

Tags: sql, hive, correlated-subquery, presto

I am trying to find the distinct count of users from the US that have performed a specific action (any row in p.action) within a 14 day rolling window, over the past ~2 months.

Here's the query. I'd love some tips on how I can re-write this to not use a correlated subquery, because Presto doesn't allow them.

```
SELECT dt,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
     FROM p.action
     WHERE dt BETWEEN q.dt - 13 AND q.dt -- period of 14 days
        AND country = 'US'
     ) AS 14d_rolling_users
FROM p.action q
WHERE dt BETWEEN '2016-08-24' AND '2016-10-24'  
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt ASC
```

I've been racking my head trying to figure out how I could accomplish this without just running 60 individual queries (one for each day).

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best do a manual rollup.

This turns each row in your table into 14 rows with additional `rollup__ds` timestamps. We then group by this new column to create a rolling 14 day window. The complexity of this is `O(N*14) = O(N)` and thus linear.

```
SELECT 
  rollup__ds,
  COUNT(DISTINCT username)
FROM (
  SELECT
    username,
    ds
  FROM
    actions
  WHERE 
    ds BETWEEN '2016-08-24' AND '2016-10-24'
    AND country = 'US'
)
CROSS JOIN 
  UNNEST(ARRAY[
    DATE_ADD('day', 0, CAST(ds AS DATE)),
    DATE_ADD('day', 1, CAST(ds AS DATE)),
    ...
    DATE_ADD('day', 12, CAST(ds AS DATE)),
    DATE_ADD('day', 13, CAST(ds AS DATE))
  ]) AS t (rollup__ds)
GROUP BY 
  rollup__ds
ORDER BY 
  rollup__ds
;
```

Hope that helps!

---

NB—*if you do NOT need distinct count best use a window function, alas this does NOT work for distinct count because they are not summable like that.*

```
SELECT 
  ds, 
  -- BEWARE this count is NOT distinct!
  SUM(COUNT(username)) over (ORDER BY ds ROWS BEWTEEN 13 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
FROM
  actions
WHERE
  ds BETWEEN '2016-08-24' AND '2016-10-24'
  AND country = 'US'
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have experience with presto, but logically, you can rewrite your query to do a Cartesian product join (join with no conditions) of `p.action` with 2 months date constraints with `p.action` with the same 2 moths date constraints, then you wouldn't need the inner query.

```
SELECT dt,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM p.action q1,p.action q2  
WHERE q1.dt BETWEEN '2016-08-24' AND '2016-10-24'  
  AND q2.dt BETWEEN '2016-08-24' AND '2016-10-24' 
  AND q1.dt BETWEEN q2.dt - 13 AND q2.dt -- period of 14 days
  AND country = 'US'
GROUP BY q1.dt
ORDER BY q1.dt ASC
```

It would be more efficient to create the 2 months table beforehand - here the conditions are applied after the join.